# Horizontal scroll at the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I want to change the scroll direction at the middle of the page.

I tried to do it with "[jInvertScroll](https://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/)", but this plugin increase `left` in css, like that:`left: /* increase on scroll */ px ;`

So if I want to change the scroll direction to the middle of the page, `left` will already have a value like:`left: -1500px;`

That's my problem.
Is there another way to do it?

HTML :

```
<div class="vertical"></div>
<div class="menu-change"></div>
<div class="horizontal"> 
  <p>scroll</p>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.scroll {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.vertical {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2500px;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random);
} 

.horizontal {
  width: 8500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random);
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.menu-change');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.horizontal').addClass('scroll');
          var elem = $.jInvertScroll(['.scroll'],
              {
              onScroll: function(percent) {
                  console.log(percent);
              }
          });
          $(window).resize(function() {
            if ($(window).width() <= 0) {
              elem.destroy();
            }
            else {
              elem.reinitialize(); 
            }
          });
       } else {
            $('.horizontal').removeClass('scroll');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: i do not know how the `html` looks like but you could use ,  set the `overflow-x : auto` , set `overflow-y : hidden` and add > `display: flex` to that `div`

Comment: i forgot to link my pen https://codepen.io/Crayzzit/pen/EQgVpb
so this is what my project looks like for the moment

Comment: oky no seeing your code the question confuses me, the div `class="horizontal"` you want to scroll horizontal to the left not right as is?

Comment: What is your problem with the left: -1500px, do you need the scroll event to animate other parts?

Comment: @Ylama the `class="horizontal` give the basics `height` `width`, when you scroll : `class="scroll"` is added to the horizontal and this class scroll contains : `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: @JoseRojas no but when i scroll the plugin increase `left` value so if i want to start scrolling horizontally at the middle of the page, `left` will already be at 1500px (for exemple)